# PL/SQL "all_search" procedure is not a procedure or is undefined

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, pipeline

This function is inside a package, but when I call the function the following error appears: PL/SQL "all_search" is not a procedure or is undefined. Someone can help me?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE employee_tab IS

       FUNCTION all_search (ID_EMP in NUMBER) RETURN O_T_EMPL PIPELINED;
                     
END employee_tab;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE O_T_EMPL AS TABLE OF O_EMPLOYEE;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY employee_tab IS 

FUNCTION all_search (ID_EMP in NUMBER) RETURN O_T_EMPL PIPELINED
        IS
          TAB_OBJC_EMP  O_T_EMPL;
          MY_QUERY_SEARCH VARCHAR2(400);
          REF_C  SYS_REFCURSOR;
          MAX_ROW NUMBER := 25;
      
        BEGIN
       
         MY_QUERY_SEARCH := 'SELECT *
                              FROM EMPLOYEES
                             WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = ID_EMP';    
            
         open REF_C for MY_QUERY_SEARCH using ID_EMP;
            
              loop
                --
                 fetch REF_C bulk collect into TAB_OBJC_EMP limit MAX_ROW;
                 exit when TAB_OBJC_EMP.count = 0;
                 for i in 1..TAB_OBJC_SEE.count
                 --
                   loop
                       pipe row(O_EMPLOYEE(TAB_OBJC_EMP(i).V_O_EMP_ID,
                                                TAB_OBJC_EMP(i).V_O_HIRE_ID,
                                                TAB_OBJC_EMP(i).V_O_DEP_ID)
                             );
         
                   end loop;
                 --
               END loop;
             --
          CLOSE REF_C;
          RETURN;
       --
        END all_search;

END employee_tab;

/
```

call function: employee_tab.all_search(1);

Comment: How are you calling the function, please provide the code snippet.

Comment: Is the declaration of the function in the package or just in the package body? Also if the function is in a package you need to call it as <package_name>.all_search(<N>).

Comment: I edited the code, put the package

Comment: It's not clear how you call the function. Pipelined functions are supposed to be called in `select * from TABLE(..)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the result of the function to something, try something like:

```
DECLARE
  l_emp_id NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT EMP_ID
    INTO l_emp_id 
    FROM TABLE(employee_tab.all_search(1))
   WHERE rownum = 1;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(TO_CHAR(EMP_ID));
END;
/
```

Comment: I understand, I'm trying to do what you sujeres but now I have another error. When calling the function in this way, the following error appears: not enough values. You can help?

Comment: It's because you're using just 3 values form the result. TAB_OBJC_EMP(i).V_O_EMP_ID, TAB_OBJC_EMP(i).V_O_HIRE_ID, TAB_OBJC_EMP(i).V_O_DEP_ID. I'm not sure what's the type of those, but you can just take any of them into a variable and it should be fine ( just remove the * and use explicit assignment to the variable and adjust the type of the l_employee of course).

Comment: Can't you edit what you told me in your solution? I'm trying to do what you suggest but still other errors appear. Types are number. I made the pipeline and I can't overcome the problem..

Comment: Does the type O_EMPLOYEE have an attribute naimed emp_id? I adjusted the query in my response, but not sure what the attributes of  O_EMPLOYEE are for sure. Can you post the O_EMPLOYEE definition in the question as well?